# Lookup that spans across 3 tables in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to do a lookup that spans three model classes. I want to find all the PartListings that match the Specific_part in the ListItem. Say Specific part = Radio, there could be several Radios in the PartListings and I want to return the PartListing id of all of them so that I can get other attributes like quantity.

I have these models:

```
class SpecificPart(BaseModel):

class PartListing(BaseModel):
    specific_part = models.ForeignKey(
        SpecificPart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,
        related_name="part_listing")

class ListItem(BaseModel):
    specific_part = models.ForeignKey(SpecificPart, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name="listitem")
```

I'm trying to put the lookup under the ListItem class like this:

```
    def item_match(self):
        part = self.specific_part
        return PartListings.filter(specific_part__specific_part=part)
```

I tried to set it up as a [Lookup that spans relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#:%7E:text=Lookups%20that%20span%20relationships&text=To%20span%20a%20relationship%2C%20use,to%20the%20field%20you%20want.)but am getting an error that PartListing is not defined. I also suspect that I'm referencing the foreign keys incorrectly. I'm also ok with redefining the models if a One to One would be better.

I am a Django newbie so thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this using [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/) between `SpecificPart` and `PartListing` models:

```
class ListItem(BaseModel):
    ...
    def item_match(self):
        return self.specific_part.part_listing.all()
```

Comment: Thanks, ruddra! This returns : `<QuerySet [<PartListing: Test Radio>, <PartListing: Test Radio>]>` How do I then get the id for these two entries from the PartsListing table so I can get other info about this like quantity?

Comment: You can use iterate through queryset to get data. Please see the documentation for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets